# check street view availability doesn't work after upgrade to swift 3.0. Google Maps sdk

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am wondering whether I get something wrong in converting, so onMoveNearCoordinate and didMoveTo function do not get called if street view is not available. And, I already updated my google maps to 2.1.0 from 2.0.1

My code right now

```
@nonobjc func panoramaView(_ view: GMSPanoramaView, error: NSError, onMoveNearCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    print("^ \(coordinate)")
    //show alert
}
```

I also try to check whether panorama is nil or not.

```
@objc(panoramaView:didMoveToPanorama:) func panoramaView(_ view: GMSPanoramaView, didMoveTo panorama: GMSPanorama?) {
    print("^ \(panorama == nil)")
}
```

didMove function do work if street view is available as I see

```
^ false
```

Here is what I get if street view is not available.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. Beware of the converting to swift3. Thanks for the help from Google developers.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=10556